# Can't use Quasar q-select methods

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

I'm a Quasar newbie and I'm facing some trouble while trying to access the q-select hidePupup method as in the [Q-Select API](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/select#qselect-api).

My current code is:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <q-select ref="myInput" :options="names" v-model="selectedNames" @update:model-value="hideInputPopup" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const selectedNames = ref([]);
const names = ref(['Pam', 'Kevin', 'Dwight', 'Jim', 'Prison Mike'])
const myInput = ref(null);

const hideInputPopup = () => {
  myInput.value.hidePopup();
};
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong? There is some different way to access Quasar's component methods?

Comment: I feel like some code is missing here. What is `hidePopup()`? Do you have a QDialog or something?

Comment: hidePopup( ) is a method of q-select that should be called to force the select list to its closure as I attached in the API above

Comment: have tested your cod in codepen and there is no issues with it. why are you trying to close the popup when an item has been clicked? this should happen automatically. what are you trying to do with the event?